# Validator for mathematical expressions in infix notation

Tags: java, parsing, validation, math-expression-eval

The function belows validates if a mathematical expression, say `12 + 2 * (9 - 3) / 4`, does not have operators that are next to each other. It returns `false` if an operator is next to another operator. Otherwise, it returns `true`. For example, if the input expression is `2++1`, it will return `false`. The function also recursively evaluates expressions that are inside pairs of parentheses.

```
private boolean validateOperators(String expression)
{
    if (!validateEndCharacters(expression)) {
        return false;
    }

    Stack s = new Stack(15); // Stack is a user-defined class.
    char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
    char prevOperator = '\0';
    String subexpression = "";
    boolean addSubexpression = false;
    boolean isValid = false;

    for (char c : expression.toCharArray()) {
        if (addSubexpression) {
            if (c == '(') {
                s.push("(");
            } else if (c == ')') {
                s.pop();
                if (s.isEmpty()) {
                    // We found the end of the expression inside the parentheses.
                    isValid &= this.validateOperators(subexpression);
                    subexpression = "";
                    prevOperator = '\0';
                    addSubexpression = false;
                }
            }

            subexpression += Character.toString(c);
        } else {
            if (c == '(') {
                addSubexpression = true;
                s.push("(");
            } else if (this.isIn(c, operators) && prevOperator == '\0') {
                prevOperator = c;
            } else if (this.isIn(c, operators) && prevOperator == '\0') {
                isValid &= false;
                break;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                prevOperator = '\0';
            }
        }
    }

    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    return isValid;
}

private boolean validateEndCharacters(String expression)
{
    char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
    if (this.isIn(expression.charAt(0), operators) ||
       this.isIn(expression.charAt(expression.length() - 1), operators)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How else can I improve the functions?

Comment: You make no use of strings poped from the stack. Actually, you just count left and right parentheses by a depth of the growing and shrinking stack, and test if it is empty or not. So it might be enough to replace the stack with a simple integer counter of the nesting depth. It would be incremented on `'('`, decremented on `')'` and tested for 0 to check a subexpression, and for (-1) to verify parens balance.

Comment: @CiaPan So if the parentheses are balanced, then the integer counter would equal to `0`. Correct?

Comment: It looks like this code never returns `true`.   `isValid` starts as false and, as far as I can see,  is never set to true.

Comment: The incoming parameter should be `Set<Character>` rather than `HashSet<Character>`, we don't really care about the concrete type, merely that it provides the correct functionality. It is still returning false for basic case http://ideone.com/qqO4br

Comment: Please don't update the code when you receive answers.  If you have another question about the new code, post a new question.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Yes, the counter equal 0 would mean there were the same number of `'('` and `')'`encountered, so if you get zero after decrementing on `')'` it will indicate an enclosed subexpression should be verified. A negative value will indicate there were more closing parentheses than opening ones, i.e. en error. Also a non-zero value at the end of input will indicate there remained some unpaired opening parentheses, i.e. an error.

Comment: @Riker, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already reuse `operators` in each methods by making it a constant. You can create a `Set` and use the `contains`method instead of `this.isIn`.

You can simplify `validateEndCharacters`, `if ( condition ) { return true } else { return false }` can always be simplified by `return condition`.

The two `else if` looks like the second block will never be executed :

```
...
} else if (this.isIn(c, operators) && prevOperator == '\0') {
    prevOperator = c;
} else if (this.isIn(c, operators) && prevOperator == '\0') {
    isValid &= false;
    break; 
}
```

Comment: +1 on suggesting on using `Set`s. I forgot to use them in the function. Good catch!